# Como posso passar uma variável em um campo de id no html?

Tags: html, ionic

Fala devs!

Tenho o seguinte problema: Em minha página html do ionic, possuo uma estrutura que cria alguns elementos com base em quantas fotos eu tenho em meu storage(banco de dados interno)

```
<ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
    <img [src]="photo.data" />
    <p>
      <ion-checkbox id="" color="primary"></ion-checkbox> 
      {{photo.description}}
    </p>
  </ion-col>
```

Ou seja, para cada foto eu crio uma div com a imagem, um checkbox e a descrição da imagem.

Eu tinha a duvida de como relacionar cada checkbox com sua imagem correspondente e cheguei a idéia de passar o ID da imagem do banco de dados para o id do checkbox. Porém como ele é gerado de forma dinâmica, queria passar a variável dentro do ID do elemento no html.

Seria algo como:

```
  <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
    <img [src]="photo.data" />
    <p>
      <ion-checkbox id="{{photo.id}}" color="primary"></ion-checkbox> 
      {{photo.description}}
    </p>
  </ion-col>
```

Isso é possível no html? Se não, como poderia faze-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta fazer da seguinte forma

```
<ion-checkbox [id]="photo.id" color="primary"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: Valeu cara! Desatenção minha não tentar utilizar o mesmo método da imagem.